# Android Chronometer starts and stops but carries on counting when stopped

Tags: android, timer, stopwatch, chronometer

I've created an app that has a toggle button to start and stop a Chronometer, like a stop watch. When you first press the toggle button (executes `.start()`), the chronometer will start counting, when you then press the button again (executes `.stop()`), the chronometer appears on screen to stop counting as it should but when it is then started again it shows that it's actually still been counting in the background and shows the time on screen as if it was never stopped

code:

```
tglStartStop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (tglStartStop.isChecked()) {

                chronStopwatch.start();
            }

            else {

                chronStopwatch.stop();
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Just a guess but it seems like you should call `setBase(...)` immediately before calling `start()`. The reason is that `start()` and `stop()` don't change the 'base' time originally set by the `setBase(...)` method. In other words, the `Chronometer` doesn't actually keep counting after it is stopped but if it's stopped / restarted the the count will be relative to the original base time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line before "chronStopwatch.start();"

```
chronStopwatch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

Comment: Isn't that what I advised in my comment on the OP's question?

Comment: @Squonk Well, you just gave a good explanation of the theory that complements nicely with the working solution provided by Giridharan.