# How to Start Chronometer from 00:00

Tags: android, chronometer

When I click on the Image Button(that should start the Chronometer )  the Chronometer doesnt start from 00:00 , but from the time the app is running .
For example  if I open the app and wait 10 sec , when I'll click on  the Imageutton then  the  Chronometer will strat from 00:10 ..
What should I do in order to start the Chronometer from 00:00 whenever i click on the image button ?

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    Chronometer focus;
    ImageButton start;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    start=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.FingerStartImageBtn);
    focus=(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            focus.start();
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Comment: Declare `Chronometer` as a `final`

Comment: did u added any code which leads to focus.start(); ? if not just try to commen out focus.start(); inside on clicklisterenr if then also the the timmer starts then there is some code that is leading to this issues

Comment: call `focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());` just before calling start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859380/android-chronometer-starts-and-stops-but-carries-on-counting-when-stopped/27859951#27859951

Comment: Problem solved  Thank you !  @Blackbelt

Answer (score 14):

Calling `focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())` just before calling `focus.start();` should do it. From the code of Chronometer

```
public void setBase(long base) {
    mBase = base;
    dispatchChronometerTick();
    updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
}

 private synchronized void updateText(long now) {
    long seconds = now - mBase;
    seconds /= 1000;
    String text = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(mRecycle, seconds);
```

as you can see the time is set to 0,

Answer (score 11):

You can give it a start time in the elapsedRealtime().

I am using below code working fine when I click on button it start from 00:00 and also you can set format like "H:MM:SS" by using

```
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
mChronometer.start();
```